# How can I combine PDFs in LibreOffice?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I'd like to be able to simply drag a pdf file into the pages explorer of a pdf that's being edited. This has no effect and dragging the file into the work area on a new page results in something like the follow:

[image]

I've also tried 'file>insert' and selecting the pdf which results in an error saying 'the file could not be loaded'.

How can I go about inserting a pdf as a page or set of pages in a pdf document I'm working on?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To combine pages from two PDFs in LibreOffice Writer follow these steps.

1. Open the first PDF document in LibreOffice Writer using *File* -> *Open*.
2. Open the second PDF document in a new LibreOffice Writer window using *File* -> *Open*.
3. Select a page in the first PDF document **Pages** pane *before* where you want to add a new page in the PDF document.
4. Select the page you want to add from the second LibreOffice window and copy it.
5. Paste the new page into the first LibreOffice Writer window.
6. Export the new PDF file using *File* -> *Export as PDF...* -> click the *Export* button -> click the *Save* button -> browse to the location where the newly created PDF file will be saved.

Comment: Opening a PDF through Writer results in the PDF being opened in LibreOffice Draw, so this solution doesn't work.

Comment: I opened in Draw and it worked fine

Comment: I open PDFs in Writer not Draw because they are easier to read in Writer, and I wouldn't be opening a PDF in Writer unless I wanted to convert it to .rtf format in order to edit it in Writer and then convert the .rtf file back to PDF after I finished editing it.

Comment: It works perfectly fine to have the PDF being opened in Draw. I copied each page separately and inserted them into empty pages inside a Writer document. The pages automatically filled the whole page, as I intended them to. Thx @karel !

Answer (score 6):

#### LibreOffice Draw

It seems that you can combine them in Draw.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/edit-pdf-documents-with-libreoffice-draw/

#### pdfsam

However my real suggestion would be to use

http://www.pdfsam.org/

#### GhostScript/PDFTK

Edit:
On Linux you can use GhostScript and pdftk

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8159842/2982543

http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/#download

Comment: I'm on linux otherwise I'd just use Acrobat DC.

Comment: If the variant in the other answer (LibreOffice Writer) does not work. I used Ghostscript on Linux before:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8159842/2982543

Comment: pdfsam wants payment to merge PDFs.

Comment: @misantroop I just checked pdfsam-basic-4.3.1: No it doesn't.
https://pdfsam.org/pdfsam-basic/

Comment: Did you try the procedure? I got a request to upgrade before finishing.

Comment: Yes. It worked fine. I used the portable version:

https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/releases/download/v4.3.1/pdfsam-4.3.1-windows.zip

Comment: Maybe you accidentally installed the enhanced version too (the installer version offers this). Try uninstalling your version first and reinstall without Enhanced trial.
 --- 
Installer version:
"Download and install PDFsam Basic on Windows systems. It offers to try PDFsam Enhanced with two free modules to view and create PDF files"

Answer (score 1):

I opened both files in Libre Office, set the two screens side by side, clicked on 'VIEW PANES' in both and dragged and dropped the pages I wanted to insert from one file to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two pdfs in Libreoffice Draw.
It is very simple and easy.

1. Just open two pdfs in Libreoffice Draw.
   (there will be two instances(right and left) of Libreoffice Draw.)
2. Copy the page in the right Libreoffice Draw.
   insert New page in the Left Libreoffice Draw.
3. Just paste it in the left.

that's all.